# mv: Directory not empty

Tags: directory, mv

I want to move content of a directory within another directory with the same folders.

Here's an example:

I have `./backup` which has the directories `base` and `test`. Now, I want to move these directories to `./backupArchives`.

I use this:

```
mv ./backup/* ./backupArchives
```

but I got the error

```
mv: cannot move './backup/base' to './backupsArchive/base': Directory not empty
```

I tried using `--force`, but no luck. Is there a way to move it when folders already exists?

Note: I just want to merge contents, there's no overwriting.

Comment: Are you just trying to merge the folders' contents into the destination, or are you trying to overwrite what's in the destination.  (it also helps if you have the ENTIRE error, without using ...... to truncate data)

Comment: I just want to merge the contents, there's no overwriting.

Comment: @UdK Even if this would work, note that this would **not** merge the contents of the two directories. Moving a directory will replace its target. Have a look at `rsync` instead, it will do the merging.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127712/merging-folders-with-mv

Comment: I got into the same situation, i was doing `mv <folder_name> ~/` from the downloads directory and was getting the error as: `mv: cannot move '<folder_name>/' to '/home/user/<folder_name>': Directory not empty` but when i did `mv <folder_name> ~/home/`, it worked, Didn't understand what solved the problem here though.

Comment: @y_159 I suspect you moved the directory either *to* or *into* a new directory called "home" inside your home directory, and it probably wasn't what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

Though its man page doesn't document it, `mv` will refuse to rename a directory to another directory if the target directory contains files. This is a good thing in your case because you turn out to want to *merge* the content of the source into the target, which `mv` will not do.

Use `rsync -a backup/ backupArchives/` instead. After that `rm -rf backup/*`.

Instead of using `rsync`, you also can do the classical

```
(cd backup && tar c .) | (cd backupArchives && tar xf -)
```

which earns you more geek points.

Comment: nice things to know! Both are working great. Thank's!

Comment: should be noted this requires you have the size of the folder in free space. And will cause horrible problems if not.

Comment: @Pogrindis Please explain what _horrible_ problems will occur, and how they are different from any other attempt to write to a full disk? Indeed, since both operations keep the original directory intact, if the operation fails you simply `rm -rf backupArchives` without consequences, let alone 'horrible' ones.

Comment: Also, must be noted, that `rsync` solution uses copying, which can be *much* slower with large files than `mv`.

Comment: how do i give bounty? this man needs 10 more the geek solution was the only one viable in my safe mode ;)!

Comment: you can use rsync's --remove-source-files option instead of removing the folder with "rm -rf backup/*" command.

Comment: Thanks for naming the classical approach, very helpful if rsync is not available! Also works with sudo using `sudo sh -c '(cd backup && tar c .) | (cd backupArchives && tar xf -)'`

Comment: @eaykin the option `--remove-source-files` only removes files from the source directory, not directories.

Comment: @Ivan "`rsync` solution uses copying, which can be much slower". The `--link-dest` option can be (ab)used in rsync to use hard-links instead of copies: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127713 (it did not work for my use case though).

Comment: What is tar xf - doing (x extract and f file, but -)?

Comment: @ArendE do I need the sh -c? The cmd as zwets writes it does nothing for me.

Comment: Worthwhile mentioning what the `-a` flag does here: "The archive mode behaves like the recursive mode but keeps all file permissions, symbolic links, file ownership, etc."

Answer (score 82):

Quick and dirty, if you know what you are doing:

```
cp -r ./backup/* ./backupArchives && rm -R ./backup/*
```

Comment: Also works in my safe mode, genious.

Comment: If you need to preserve permissions and last modified time, then add --preserve

Comment: I get `'p: invalid option -- '`. My cp seems to be broken.

Comment: May want to add "./backup/.*" to the cp command since a straight * won't catch hidden files

Answer (score 11):

After the directory you moving you need `*` (represents any text or number). For example:

```
mv /var/www/* /recovery/wwwrecovery/
```

thats all, if you moving files, than you move as:

`mv /var/www/index.php /recovery/index.php`

Another way is to pack that folder content by using tar:

```
tar -cvzpf backup.tar.gz /var/www
```

Then move it lie any other file. Also I recommend this step because tar compresses it and make it smaller in size.

To extract the files to another folder use

```
tar -xvzpf /var/www/
```

If you need to copy to a location you don't own, make sure to prepend your command with the `sudo` command after whichever option you decide to use.

```
sudo tar -cvzpf backup.tar.gz /var/www/
```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and I got:
mv: invalid option -- 'R'
Try `mv --help' for more information.

Indeed .tar is nice, but I need to know how to move my files for this situation.
Thank's for your help

Comment: i using 12.04 desktop and server and in both works well. be carefull, if you didnt make space betwen folfer and -R. i also tryed without -R works in same way for me, try without -R, but be carefull with spelling: linux matters lower and uppercase letters!!! than if path is incorect movingin or movingfrom location. if you dont have that folder that you wana move to just put -C after it and it will create it. also try first: find -iname *name of your folder*  and run this command from root, just to see if it exists in other place if you miss spelled something. give me exact command that you used

Comment: what thaaa..... put that filename in betwen **

Comment: That `-R` surely shouldn't come after the first argument. Options (nearly) always precede the command arguments. Also, `mv` has no `-R` option, and finally, recursion is irrelevant to a `mv`. @DimitrisTheodoridis please test your answer first.

Comment: yes my bro you are right, i always have problems with my spelling, and allways i have problem with terminal for that or command not found or create new files and directories that i dont know, just for bas spelling... by the way i used cp command, than here wrote mv sory for that bro :D

Comment: hey sorry, i will modiffy my answer so look back on it i made big mistake as i writte to you about mv and worked with something else. take look again

Comment: Ss'x1xx s so ex sc1 x ex x ex xxxxx SD s x ez SD x'xzzz ZZZ zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz0

Comment: The `mv` solution doesn't work if there are subdirectories in common (would expand to ex. `mv /var/www/include /recovery/wwwrecovery/`, breaking if `include` folder is already present in the dest directory). It also might not work if there are hidden files (in bash you'd either need `shopt -s dotglob` or, assuming no hidden file has a single-character name, `mv /var/www/* /var/www/.??* /recovery/wwwrecovery/` ).

Answer (score 5):

I had to copy a very large directory with a lot of large files, so I created [hardlinks](https://ostechnix.com/explaining-soft-link-and-hard-link-in-linux-with-examples/) to the original files in the target directory like this:

```
cp -al ./backup/* ./backupArchives
```

Then I deleted the originals, leaving only one hardlink to each file.

Since hardlinks are quite space efficient, you could even use hardlinks to copy the `backupArchives` and `backup` directories to a new trial location, and check that the file counts are as you expect, as a dummy run. This assumes that your filesystem supports hardlinks - ext4 does.

Answer (score 4):

Sure `rsync` does work, but this might work as well for machine that does not support `rsync` (i.e in cpanel, which rsync is not installed by default).

What about using:

```
cd /path/to/backup/ && cp -R --parents ./* ../backupArchives
```

Then remove the `backup` directory if necessary

Note1: You need to `cd` to the `backup` directory before executing the `cp -R --parents ...`

Note2: Double check the `backupArchives` directory if you got the new files from backup.

Answer (score 1):

Before asking the question, let's consider a simplified case.

Suppose in /home/admin we have two folders `foo` and `bar` which have the same subdirectory structure, but each contains different files in it. Now we want to merge them into one. When we do things like `mv foo/* bar`, the error `mv: directory not empty` occurs.

My solution is to give up command line tools and switch to a GUI file manager, for example, dolphin. When you rename `foo` to `bar` in dolphin, it gives you the option to write into the destination folder, and asks you whether to overwrite existing files, interactively. This avoids copy and delete, which in effect saves your time without a single line of code.

PS: I didn't test every file manager out there. But most of them should have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

When moving directory ***during a script execution***, you need to consider non-existing or empty directories, and also force override and removal without confirmation:

```
# If old directory exists, and isn't empty
if [[ -d old_dir ]] && [[ -n `ls -A old_dir` ]] ; then

  # Make a new directory (skip if already exists)
  mkdir -p new_dir

  # Copy all files to the new directory (-afr : Keep attributes, Force overwrite, Recursive copy)
  cp -afr old_dir/* new_dir/

  # Remove old directory
  rm -rf old_dir
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem of merging 2 directory trees, and didn't want to `rsync` or `cp` because it would have taken too long. The content was over 2TB, and since the destination was on the same disk, `mv` did it in a few seconds.

So this is one way of doing it:

- find files to move
- create the destination directory if needed
- move the file (overwriting the destination file if it already exists)

```bash
cd $your_source_dir # go to your source dir.
dest=".."  # moving files to the parent dir. Replace with your destination

find . -type f | while read f; do
    d=$(dirname "$f")
    file=$(basename "$f")
    mkdir -p "$dest/$d"
    mv -f "$f" "$dest/$d/"
done
```

After that, the source directory still has all the empty folders. They can be removed with

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```