# How do I move a subfolder with contents to a different source folder without copying?

Tags: command-line, mv

I know it's been asked a million times, but I can't find the answer to what I'm trying to do specifically.

Here's the directory structure:

```
Main Folder1
|
|-Subfolder 1
|-Subfolder 2 HasAReallyLongName
|---files
|-Subfolder 3-1000

Main Folder2
|
|-Subfolder 2 HasAReallyLongName
|---files
```

- I want to try to achieve moving Subfolder2 with its files to a
  different directory.
- I don't want to copy and then remove anything because I don't have enough space.
- I don't want to `mv /Main/Sub2/* /Main2/` because that puts everything in the `/Main2` folder and not in a subdirectory.
- I don't want to `mkdir /Main2/...` because it's a really long name (timestamps mostly) and I don't want to manually type it (and probably mess it up)
- As far as I know, `rsync` copies the files too, so I'm not sure that it
  would work.

Any suggestions or other tools would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try, `mv /Main/Sub2 /Main2/`. See if it helps. Note the subtle difference in our commands.

Comment: @amanthethy I got the error "folder not empty" and also tried it with the -f switch. Still nothing.

Comment: Sorry try with the `-r` flag. Or even `-rf`.

Comment: `-r` is an invalid option... `cp` has a -r for recursive but not `mv`

Answer (score 3):

This is completely straightforward.

```
mv /Main1/Sub2 /Main2
```

This creates the directory `/Main2/Sub2` with all the contents of the original, and deletes the directory `/Main1/Sub2`. If you don't want to type the full name, you can use a glob; just stop typing the name and end with `*` when you have entered enough characters to distinguish the directory name from everything else in the directory (be careful!):

```
mv /Main/Sub* /Main2
```

Possible problems that could be causing this not to work as expected:

- There is already a directory inside `/Main2` with the same name as `/Main1/Sub2`. This causes the error `directory not empty`, as `mv` is refusing to overwrite the existing directory. If this is the case, rename (or remove) the existing directory in `/Main2` first:

  ```
  mv /Main2/Sub2 /Main2/SomethingElse
  ```
- Using an incorrect path. Remember that everything is case sensitive and be aware of relative paths and `~` expansion. These are all different depending on the current working directory

  ```
  /Main1/Sub2
  Main1/Sub2
  ~/Main1/Sub2
  ```
- You do not have permission to write to the source and/or destination directory. This will be very obvious from the error message: `mv: cannot move 'thing' to '/place': Permission denied`. In which case you can run my favourite command to overcome the problem

  ```
  sudo !!
  ```

Comment: This does not work, still copying occur. I am trying to move 90 Gb file from home folder to root

Comment: What does not work? What are you doing and what error are you getting? @EugeneMala

Comment: In my case mv always copied files because I tried to move file from password encrypted home folder

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the directory already existing at the destination causes that error. I was dumbfounded because I thought it was supposed to be a simple command but I wrongly assumed that an earlier command had failed to create a directory.

Answer (score -1):

Got it:
Using `sudo mv /Main1/Sub2 /Main2` did it for me.
The main difference is being root I suppose.

Comment: Actually this only works sometimes for whatever reason... Sometimes when I run the `sudo mv` command, it'll still show "Directory not empty" error...

Comment: There's an article about that ERROR message here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/269775/mv-directory-not-empty

Seems to be caused by the FOlder not being empty. So the first time would work with mv, but it'll fail after that.

Comment: That is incorrect, it is not a permissions issue. The problem is that the directory you are trying to move that one to contains a directory with the same name. You can achieve what you want by first removing or renaming the directory `/Main2/Sub2`. After that, `mv /Main1/Sub2 /Main2` will work as expected